# Simplify nested if else condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, nested-if

I have this nested if else condition. The flow of the checks that I want is described in below code.

```
if (HiringManagerAPPROVED)
{ 
    //email reporting gropu
}
else if (ReportingGroupAPPROVED)
{ 
    //email Hiringmanager
}
else if (HiringManagerReAPPROVED)
{ 
    //email PPO
}                }
else if (PpoAPPROVED)
{ 
    //email Finance
}
else if (FinanceAPPROVED)
{ 
    //email president & COO
}
else if (PresidentCooAPPROVED)
{ 
    //email hr
}
else if (HRAPPROVED)
{
    //email Hiring Manager
}
```

How to reduce number of checks , keeping the flow of the checks as it is.

Comment: You need to rethink your design. Maybe store who approved in a list any loop through them or whatever. And try codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If that's the entire list then I've seen a lot worse!

Comment: It is not nested if else

Comment: I would try to refactor that into a `Switch(){}` statement and use multiple switches if necessary.. but I have seen way worse code perhaps you could show a little more context in regards to your code so we can get an even better understanding

Comment: Convert your flags to enums & then convert to a switch statement.

Comment: A good approach could be to use key-value collection (dictionary). UserType as key, and emailAddress as value (even can store method as value). That would decrease line count dramatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Finance`, `Ppo`, and `HiringManager` could be users, but they look to me more look like roles.

Either way, what you'd probably end up doing is having a collection of Role objects, each with an `IsApproved` field

```
public class Role
{
    public RoleType Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    //etc
}

public enum RoleType
{
    Finance,
    HiringManager,
    //etc
}
```

After you do that, you can replace your if statements with this

```
List<Role> roles = new List<Role>();
// populate your roles how you like

foreach (Role role in roles)
{
    if (role.IsApproved)
    {
        // email roll
    }
}
```

Bear in mind, that if all you're going to do with these roles is send an email if they're approved, then you're not going to get much of an advantage with this approach.

The advantage comes when you have to do other things with the roles based on how they're approved, or even based on other criteria.

Comment: Your code will send emails to all `Approved` roles. But OP code sends it to the only one role.

Comment: @Shaharyar That's a feature

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to turn this into a switch.
Here's some pseudo-code:

```
switch($group) {
  case "HiringManager":
    // do stuff
    break;

  case "Reporting":
    // do stuff
    break;

  case "HiringManagerRe":
    // do stuff
    break;

  case "Ppo":
    // do stuff
    break;

  case "Finance":
    // do stuff
    break;

  case "PresidentCoo":
    // do stuff
    break;

  case "HR":
    // do stuff
    break;
}
```

What you probably want to do is set the email address in each case, and then just send mail based off whatever addresses you set.

```
send_email($addresses);
```

Comment: Personally I don't think that's an improvement!

Comment: That depends on the language you are using. When compiled, switches can actually execute faster than ifelse statements, so it would be a performance improvement if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I might be reading too much into this, but it looks like  you're trying to do a simple workflow, where the state of the hiring process determines what happens and what happens next.  Without knowing more about your architecture this feels like a really good place to employ a simple state machine, or more likely Command Pattern to create the actual workflow. This allows each step to be nicely encapsulated and tested, and it also allows you to be a lot more flexible in terms of what happens when in the future.

There's a few different ways to do it, but one is spelled out here pretty well: http://salakoahmed.blogspot.com/2008/08/command-pattern-as-workflow-patter.html